# Converting an non ARC project to ARC error

Tags: iphone, ios

When I converting my `iPhone` project to `Objective - c ARC` I am getting the same error all the time:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-fktzngidcyimjibgdosyphgbuzpe/Build/Intermediates/TestApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/TestApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TestAppCommand /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo failed with exit code 1
```

Please can someone advice me how can I resolve this?

Comment: Not with that level of information, no.

Comment: What is your project architecture ?

Comment: Try clean and build for simulator.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 3rd party libraries that don't support ARC you should just add this flag to the files in question in your build phases/compile sources (prevents ARC on only those files). This should help you determine if your code is the issue or the library you are using (if that's the case).

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

I solved this issue by changing the value of the Valid Architecture found in Project > Build Settings  Architectures from the default "armv6 armv7" to "armv7". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you added the -fno-objc-arc flag to each implementation file (.m file).

And then clean the project (Project menu -> clean) and build again. I have sometimes had to clean and build twice when doing this in class. Seems like a little bug.